# Amazon API : Price is not available for all the products returned by API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

We are searching in the Indian Locale.

Required Search Parameters are as follows:

```
"SearchIndex"=>"Apparel",
"Keywords" =>"Kurta",
"Availability" => "Available",
"ResponseGroup" => "Medium,Offers"
```

We look for the product price in `$item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->FormattedPrice.`

When we check for the Product URL and visit the actual product details page on amazon.in, the price is displayed, however the price is not returned by the API.
Also, SalePrice is not returned for all the products.
Are we missing something? OR Is this a bug?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out that A product having parent ASIN will not show a price because it is just a container for the child ASINs. So we can add "Variations" in the response group to get the prices of the child ASIN. This worked only for Apparels.